# How do I run every string in a list in python? (os.startfile)

Tags: python

I want to run every file in a list with os.startfile() but I have no clue how to do it and haven't messed with arrays much. I've tried 'os.startfile(list)' but that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how?

List example:

```
list = ['C:\Programme Files\example1.exe', 'C:\Programme Files\example2.exe', 'C:\Programme Files\example3.exe', ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for path in list:
    os.startfile(path)
```

Also, you might want to change 'list' to a different name, because IDE's usually highlight the word list, which makes it look weird.